# Concurrent Dictionary AddOrUpdate vs Index Add

Tags: c#

There are two ways I've assigned values to a existing key in a concurrent dictionary in my current project.

A. `concurrentDictionary1[key] = value`;

and

B. `concurrentDictionary2.AddOrUpdate(key, value, (k, v) => value);`

If I know that the 'key' exists, are these functionally equivalent?

Is protection offered by the concurrency of the Concurrent Dictionary bypassed with method 'A'?

What is the difference here? What are the reasons for choosing one over the other?

I looked through the documentation at msdn, and it seems they only initialize a concurrent dictionary with method 'A', not update it.

Comment: As a side note, [I found these benchmarks](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/dictionary-vs-concurrentdictionary) which compare the speeds of updating values in a multithreaded-environment. Most of the time a regular Dictionary with locking beat out a ConcurrentDictionary.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They both call `TryAddInternal`, so behave exactly the same**.

Update:

There is another difference.  Here's the code from the indexer:

```
set
{
    TValue tValue;
    if (key == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
    }
    this.TryAddInternal(key, value, true, true, out tValue);
}
```

vs. from the method

```
while (!this.TryAddInternal(key, tValue, false, true, out tValue1));
```

So it appears there is a chance that the indexer will fail silently, whereas the method will continue trying until it succeeds.  Hmm, some more in-depth analysis would be required to fully understand the differences between the two :/

Decompilers are *still* your friend.

**I derped.

Comment: This `concurrentDictionary1[key] = value` would not throw an exception if the key doesn't exists, instead it will add it to the dictionary.

Comment: This is my fear, it seems that the indexer is good for initializing but may act unexpectedly where concurrency is actually needed.

Comment: You're not fully correct. Actually indexed will do its work if you just want to unconditionally add or update the value. `AddOrUpdate()` should be used when you want to update the value based on existing one, that's why this method uses `while` to ensure that you get the most actual value in `updateFactory` (therefore it may be called several times).

Comment: I think you use one or the other depending on if you need to look at the existing value or not. It does not make any sense IMO to use AddOrUpdate if I am just trying to add without caring about the existing value.

Answer (score 42):

This is an old question, but no one answered why you would use one over the other.

Choose A (the indexer) if you want to add or update and the update is not dependent on the existing value.

Choose B (AddOrUpdate) if you want to add or update and the update depends on an existing value. AddOrUpdate will do the update atomically.

So in the case in the question, you want to use the indexer. It's simpler, easier to read, and probably faster since you aren't creating an anonymous function.

Answer (score 4):

> If I know that the 'key' exists, are these functionally equivalent?

The way you're using it, yes.  In fact, they're equivalent whether `key` exists or not.

> What are the reasons for choosing one over the other?

`AddOrUpdate` accepts a *function* to be used to update the value.  You're just using it to set the value directly, but it is designed to be used to update the value in a concurrent fashion based on the result of a function.  For example:

```
concurrentDictionary2.AddOrUpdate(key, value, (k, v) => v + value);  // adds value to the existing value
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes equivalent.
No. indexers are actually methods (like properties are) and i dont think they bypass concurrency for that.
method

Comment: Method A will not throw an exception if the key doesn't exists, instead it will add it to the dictionary.

Comment: oh yes ive mixed it up with normal Dictionary.

Comment: well that's the normal behaviour of the normal dictionary as well.