# What takes less CPU time/ what is faster/smaller load? AddOrUpdate or if/else with TryAdd?

Tags: c#, load, cpu-usage, concurrentdictionary, cpu-time

I have KeyValuePairs and i want to add the new value to a ConcurrentDictonary. If the key is not contained i want to add it.
But what is faster/better:

this:

```
dict.AddOrUpdate(pair.Key, pair.Value, (ok, ov) => pair.Value);
```

or this:

```
if (dict.ContainsKey(pair.Key))
{
    dict[pair.Key] = pair.Value;
}
else
{
    dict.TryAdd(pair.Key, pair.Value);
}
```

I am concerned that the AddOrUpdate does additional work that i don't want/need and that it takes longer because the Lambda has to be executed too.

Which of those two methods is faster? Or is there a even faster Method?

Comment: Why don't you try it out?

Comment: how can i try it out?

Comment: Do a large loop with a timer?

Comment: Use the `Stopwatch` class to start one, run your operation (I'd suggest a large amount of operations to more clearly see a/ the difference) stop your Stopwatch and look how long it took

Comment: The two codes are not equivalent, testing is pointless. if you want thread safety use AddOrUpdate. if thread safety is not issue, then just use Dictionary not ConcurrentDictionary

Comment: i don't have appropriate data to test this. and i think i would have to run the test for days or at least for hours to see a significant difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AddOrUpdate in concurrent dictionary is atomic operation, if you separate that to two method calls `ContainsKey` and `TryAdd` its no longer atomic and so defeats the purpose of concurrent dictionary. You should not worry about performance in this case.

> I am concerned that the AddOrUpdate does additional work that i don't want/need

The two codes are not equivalent. if you want thread safety use `AddOrUpdate`. if thread safety is not issue, then just use `Dictionary` which is simpler and faster than `ConcurrentDictionary`

> and that it takes longer because the Lambda has to be executed too.

executing lambdas are as fast as executing other methods (if you don't fall into micro optimizing ofcourse)

Comment: in my case i would need to override the AddOrUpdate to add additional code. Same goes for the TryAdd. So no matter which method i use those functions aren't atomic anymore. but the additional code should have no inpact on thread safety.

Comment: Can i use the ContainsKey and the TryAdd and still be threadsafe? for example by locking the ConcurrentDictionary?

Comment: does this add the KeyValuePair if it is not already in the ConcurrentDictonary?

Comment: @MidnightCommander sorry, don't use indexer. it wont be thread safe. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17926519/concurrent-dictionary-addorupdate-vs-index-add specifically this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17926706/4767498

Comment: I'm not so good at english. So adding something unconditionally means that it's not thread safe. Did i get that right? Or what does "unconditionally" mean in this context?  @M.kazem Akhgary

Comment: it's thread safe, but if `dict[key] = value` fails , it wont try again. but `AddOrUpdate` tries until it successfully add or update. @MidnightCommander

Comment: thank you, that already helps me. And what does it mean to store something unconditionally?

Comment: if you are referring to that comment, by "unconditionally" he meant "without the while loop". if you look at the code showed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17926706/4767498 you will see that `AddOrUpdate` uses a while loop until it can successfully do add or update. but `dict[key] = value` (the first code) only calls TryAddInternal once, without the while loop (unconditionally). @MidnightCommander

Comment: You may want to use the indexer. now that i think about it, i would use indexer myself. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23961609/4767498 @MidnightCommander